# How to list all files in a tree along with the touch timestamp and write to CSV in bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, fs

I have millions of files in a tree. I to write the full path to all *files* (not directories), *along with the last touched timestamp*, to a CSV file, from bash. I was going to start writing a script in Node.js but it is a little tricky so I wanted to see if there was a way to take advantage of piping/streaming in bash to do this in just a few lines.

```
find dir -type f \
  -name '*.html' \
  -o -name '*.jpg' \
  -o -name '*.json' \
  -o -name '.png' \
  -o -name '.gif' | \
  get timestamp | \
  write csv rows...
```

The output would be like:

```
dir/some/file,<timestamp>
dir/some/file2,<timestamp>
...
```

If it's absolute or relative path doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `find` that supports it, just use `find dir ... -printf '%p,%a\n'`

If not, try:

```
find dir ... -exec stat --format='%n,%x' {} +
```

I don't know what you mean by "last touched timestamp", and maybe you want mtime, but each of the above gives atime.  You can get mtime with %t and %y.  Check the documentation.

Comment: Got `stat: illegal option -- -` and `usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`, and for the first one, `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`. I'm on mac.

Comment: On macos, try `find . -exec stat -f '%N,%a' {} +`.  Also, consider `man stat`

Answer (score 0):

`find .  -type f -name  '*.html'   -o -name '*.jpg'   -o -name '*.json'  -o -name '*.png'  -o -name '*.gif' | xargs -I{} ls -l {}  | awk '{OFS=","}{print $9 , $6" "$7" "$8 }' > output.csv`  "." after find is for current directory , you can replace it with the directory path